# How configure Web-Service client to use ws-at (WS-Transaction) on Liberty Profile?

Tags: web-services, distributed-transactions, websphere-liberty

I need to call a WebService using WS-Transaction, but my webservice client is running on IBM Liberty Profile, so how I can configure my server or application to send the Coordination Context with my SOAP request?

If I were using Websphere Application Server, I should associated a policySet to endpoint, how to use the policy set on Liberty Profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liberty profile does yet support WS-AtomicTransaction. Please vote for the request for enhancement at the following URL to show your requirement for this feature. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=61348

Answer (score 0):

Good news that Liberty support WS-AT since late 2015 build (up to 2015 Nov, it is in beta, try https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/)